# Why does findIndex on an empty array does not return -1?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show alert only once in the following program:

```
const errorToBeShownOnce = [];

export const anExampleOfAFunction = () => {
    const num = 1;
    try {
        num.toUpperCase(); // You cannot convert a number to upper case
    } catch (err) {
        if (errorToBeShownOnce.findIndex(err.message) === -1) {
            alert(err.name, err.message);
            errorToBeShownOnce.push(err.message);
            console.log("table in if: " + errorToBeShownOnce)
        } else {
            return
        }
    } finally {
        console.log("final action");
    }
};

export const functionToShowErrorMessage = () => {
    setInterval(anExampleOfAFunction, 10000);
};
```

I believe that `errorToBeShownOnce.findIndex(err.message)` should equal `-1` as there is no data in the array originally but it looks like it does not. I am trying to understand what the issue is here? Am I not able to use `findIndex` on an empty array?
Could anyone assist me with this case?

Comment: Check the docs for `findIndex`. You probably meant `indexOf`. The difference is that `findIndex` takes a callback function as its parameter and `indexOf` takes an element.

Comment: You should not declare `errorToBeShownOnce` as `const` if you're going to modify it.

Comment: @rcbgalido That's incorrect, `errorToBeShownOnce` is an array, pushing to the array doesn't modify the reference.

Comment: @rcbgalido you can't reassign `const` variables. You can mutate the array

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) accepts a callback as an argument and not a `string`. So I guess if you really want use `findIndex` to check if you showed that error message earlier, you could do something like this:

```js
const errorMessage = 'randomError';
const errorToBeShownOnce = [];
const result = errorToBeShownOnce.findIndex(e => e === errorMessage);

console.log(result);
```

As you see the `result` will be `-1` in this case.

From the documentation:

> The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.

Or as suggested, you can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you have a string, just like the following:

```js
const errorMessage = 'randomError';
const errorToBeShownOnce = [];
const result = errorToBeShownOnce.indexOf(errorMessage);

console.log(result);
```

From the documentation:

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

findIndex argument need to be function. Check the below, if you pass function on empty array it will return -1.

```js
// console.log([].findIndex('some string')) // this will get type error
console.log([].findIndex(() => {}))  // will return -1
```